# Plymouth just shows symbols instead of boot animation in Debian Buster

Tags: debian, grub2, nvidia, plymouth, bootsplash

## ASK: How can I properly configure my Plymouth Boot Screen?

- I have Debian Buster 10.4 **XFCE**.
- I set `quiet` and `splash` boot parameters in my grub.
- `sudo plymouth --show-splash` doesn't work.
- At shutdown, Plymouth just doesn't appear.
- At startup, Plymouth is shown as a strange colored screen that doesn't fit my screen resolution. That screen has three blocks of text (square symbols) blinking with the common loading pattern (**X**XX - X**X**X - XX**X** - **X**XX - etc)
- I did try to change the Plymouth Theme without success.

It is to note that I have the NVIDIA Proprietary Drivers installed on my system, but the [official configuration](https://wiki.debian.org/plymouth#Configuration) of the Debian Wiki just shows the below way for the `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`:

> For **Nouveau** (nVidia)
>
> ```
> # KMS
> drm
> nouveau modeset=1
> ```

Comment: I did set ´GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep´ and I can see the boot animation at startup now. At shutdown the screen blanks.